# Can you install hardwood floors on a concrete slab?

Tags: hardwood-floor

I was told the slab is like a sponge and the moisture would ruin the floor.

Comment: See also: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8717/can-i-lay-down-solid-wood-planks-on-top-of-my-basement-concrete-floor

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to ever install a wood floor directly on a concrete slab (despite what your contractor might say), even using the traditional underlayment.

You have to create a buffer between the concrete and wood with something like [DRIcore®](http://www.dricore.com/en/eIndex.aspx) or [DELTA®-FL](http://www.cosella-dorken.com/bvf-ca-en/products/foundation_residential/floor/products/fl.php).

Though I have heard that even with systems like this, you can still run into problems if the moisture gets under the sub-floor and can't escape. Mold and rot can develop if moisture can't escape, so you'll want to make sure any moisture that gets in can always get out.